# Java regular expression search and replace

Tags: java, search, replace

What is wrong with this code?

```
public int convert(String param){
    System.out.println(param); // OUTPUT1 
    if(param=="NUM1"){
      return 10;
    }else if(param=="NUM2"){
      return 20;
    }else
      return 0;
    }
    return param;
}

String Formula="[NUM1]+[NUM2]";
Formula = Formula.replaceAll("\\[(.*?)\\]", convert("$1") );
System.out.println(Formula); // OUTPUT2 

//OUTPUT1 - $1
//OUTPUT2 - 0+0
```

I want OUTPUT1 to be (NUM1 or NUM2) and OUTPUT2 to be "10+20".

Comment: @Gorets 19 questions with 4 accepted, 14 answers with 1 accepted and 65 rep. I don't think you are in any position to make remarks like that.

Comment: thank for answer. can you guideline code me for solve a problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Java, one can't just use `"$1"` to reference portions of matched expressions like scripting languages. Instead capture groups are used.

You should start by reading the javadoc for [Pattern](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Not the best thing:

```
String line = "[NUM1]+[NUM2]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[(.*?)\\]");
Matcher m = p.matcher(line);
while(m.find()) {
    String token = m.group(1);
    String newValue = convert(token);
    line = line.replaceAll(token, newValue);
}
```

Comment: thank for answer. can you guideline code me for solve a problem?

Comment: Added code. Sorry for being short earlier.

Answer (score 1):

Java isn't a functional language (yet, v8 might change add them).  It looks like what you are trying to do is pass in a callback function to the replaceAll, but that's not going to work in Java.

What you'd need to do is instead of using replaceAll, use a Matcher and get all the tokens, then loop through them and call convert() on each token adding it back into the string.  Its a lot more trouble, but its the only way to go if you want to build it yourself.

Comment: thank for answer. can you guideline code me for solve a problem?